# How does time() in time.h work?

Tags: c, interrupt

Let's I call the time function from my code and save the value. Then I disable interrupts and some code gets executed that takes a non-trivial amount of time to execute. Then I renable the interrupts and get the value from the time function.

```
start = time ( NULL );
disable_interrupts();
...


...
enable_interrupts()
end = time ( NULL );
```

I'm getting the exact same value for start and end? How can disabling interrupts cause this weird behavior?

Comment: What os/kernel/CPU arch are you on? (Using interrupts for simple time tracking is not infrequent at all.)

Comment: Does the whole process take less than 1 second?

Comment: If you increase the work done within the section, do you not see a change in time difference?

Comment: Disabling interrupts for a non-trivial amount of time can cause all sorts of behaviors - stopping clocks is only one possibility.

Comment: The code is about 15 seconds o so, I understand playing around with interrupts is not a good idea but I really need to do that for this thing I'm working on

Comment: What exactly are you doing that's more important than the basic functions of the computer? I'd have a hard time believing there's not a better solution that doesn't involve disabling interrupts globally. And for 15 seconds honestly scares me.

Comment: You haven't answered the most/only relevant question, which is **what os/kernel/cpu arch are you on?** Unless you're writing your own OS, disabling interrupts is absolutely the wrong solution to whatever you're trying to do, and even then, disabling them for 15 seconds is bogus.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your platform/OS (and this feels like an embedded type), some implementations of time use either timer interrupts or even count vblank/hblank interrupts.  Turning off interrupts and getting this results seems to confirm this.  BTW, I concur with others in that turning off interrupts for any non-trivial amount of time is borrowing a LOT of trouble.  Unless you know exactly what is going on, and I mean exactly, you can easily shoot yourself in the foot and not even know it until months later.